# Palette does not render arrows since Wicket 7.x.x

Tags: wicket

See this minimal demo at GitHub: https://github.com/ErikVerheul/PaletteBugDemo.git

I expected that the code line palette.add(new DefaultTheme()); would do the trick. However, it did not.

When changing the Wicket version to 6.20.0 all works fine.

Did I miss something?

help appreciated,
Erik

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: Remove your paragraph `<p>` and use a `<div>` instead of the `<span>` for the palette.

**Long answer**

The `p` paragraph cannot contain other block elements. In Wicket 6.x the palette uses a `table` to layout the "Available" und "Selected" options. In Wicket 7.x `div`s are used for that, since tables only should be used for tabular data and not for layouting. Neither tables nor divs are allowed in a paragraph though. I guess browsers are just a bit more forgiving when using tables at wrong places, hence you are seeing a somewhat correct result with version 6.x.

Another problem is that you are using a `span` tag for your palette. Again, the palette is inserting either a `table` or several `div` tags, but neither of these are valid in between the span tag.

So something like this should do it:

```
<form>
  <div class="mystyle">
    <div wicket:id="palette"></div>
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem SOLVED. Thank you Martin! As a Wicket novice I used a version 6 example not knowing the changes in version 7. The working version is now on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks. I also missed the "palette.add(new DefaultTheme());" change

Answer (score 0):

It does work fine here: http://examples7-apachewicket.rhcloud.com/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.PalettePage

Please check what is different in your app.

Comment: Are you sure these examples are compiled with <wicket.version>7.x.x</wicket.version>? I noticed that you use wicket-devutils-6.0.0.SNAPSHOT. Sounds like Wicket 6.

Comment: When debugging in Firefox I notice that my demo misses a palette.css file with content:....

button.button.add div {
 background: url("add.gif"); 
 height: 15px; 
 width: 15px;
}

button.button.remove div {
 background: url("remove.gif"); 
 height: 15px; 
 width: 15px;
}

button.button.up div {
 background: url("up.gif"); 
 height: 15px; 
 width: 15px;
}

button.button.down div {
 background: url("down.gif"); 
 height: 15px; 
 width: 15px;
}

Comment: `I noticed that you use wicket-devutils-6.0.0.SNAPSHOT` - I am not sure how you got this impression. This is Wicket 7.0.0. Just double checked and it uses devutils-7.0.0.

Comment: I tried to extent my Homepage with WicketExamplePage. Then I had to find more dependencies. Netbeans found wicket-devutils-6.0.0. But anyway, thanks for your help so far. I must definitely made an error somewhere.