# How to include default css file for Wicket Palette?

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-7

I have the same problem as described in [Palette does not render arrows since Wicket 7.x.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740642/palette-does-not-render-arrows-since-wicket-7-x-x)

The example includes a link with the href palette-ver-48087C00867DD23918CC93E129A02A8D.css.

How can I include the css file from 1) an imported jar file, or 2) from the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/5d87f50646d13d858eab69d7892075be8cdb1dbd/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/compref/PalettePage.java#L54

In the demo page for the Wicket Examples the Palette component uses DefaultTheme behavior to contribute palette.css.
You could use your own Behavior to contribute custom theme.

Comment: I added 'palette.add(new DefaultTheme());' which is a big improvement. However, the four arrows appear one button below where they should be. i.e. top button is empty, down arrow is not on a button.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static final ResourceReference Custom = new CssResourceReference(DefaultTheme.class,
            "mypalette.css");


    public Palette(final String id, final IModel<? extends Collection<T>> model,
            final IModel<? extends Collection<? extends T>> choicesModel,
            final IChoiceRenderer<? super T> choiceRenderer, final int rows, final boolean allowOrder,
            boolean allowMoveAll).add(new DefaultTheme().renderHead(this,Custom);
```